# Regex Expression validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#-4.0

Regex to check the first character is in uppercase and allow only alphanumeric,not allow the special charcter.
Thank you Advance

```
    function checkName(val) {    
    var alpha = document.getElementById(val).value;    
    var filter = /^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*$/;    
    if (!filter.test(alpha)) {
        alert("Please Enter Alphanumeric Only");
        return false;                                                   
    } 
    return true;   
  }
```

> i Used This its working properly for checking alphanumeric but for
>   first character uppercase its not working
>   where can i modify my regex expression or any solution.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+/
```

For example

```
/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+/.test("Asd");
```

Comment: if i replace my regex expression with your regex then alert messege will popup at every time if i enter alphanumeric letters also

Comment: @Shafi74 it won't if  you enter first character as uppercase.

Comment: If I enter first character as lowercase  it should be validate

Comment: @Shafi74 are you saying that if first character is lowercase then also it is valid? Then you question is not in synch with your comment.

Comment: i will give an example if i enter first character as lowercase like aBCD then alert messege should be (First Letter Shoulb Be UpperCase) or automaticaly first character will change like ABCD. Thanq For responding please fulfill my requirement either using regex or any methods